# Visual Query Builder component for WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms

Do you have any recommendations for a free or cheap visual query builder component which can be used in my WinForms app?

I know of EasyQuery and ActiveQuery, but they cost hundreds of dollars!

EDIT: This is SQL queries that I am talking about.

Comment: Try to create one yourself :)

Comment: Do you mean SQL-Queries? Like [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports)?

Comment: Did you ever find a good componoent for this